# Apply UUID function to database field from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this CodeIgniter and MySQL application.

I have a database table where one field must be unique. When I "delete" a record from the table I don't want to really remove it from the table, I just want to set free the value of the unique field so it can be used for a future new record without conflicts and leave it there.

At first I tought applying some sort of UUID function to the field would be a good solution.
Can somebody please point me how can I apply the UUID function to the field from the PHP code?
I googled about it and couldn't come up with nothing, CodeIgniter's docs neither.

Some other toughts are also welcome and appreciated.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: You want to make UUIDs reusable? This a) kind of goes against the idea of UUIDs and is b) usually unnecessary since there's no shortage of UUIDs. Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: No, I want to make the unique field(let's say username) value reusable by changing it for an UUID at "deletion" time. That way the "deleted" record can remain on the table and the username value can be reused.

Comment: OK, I see. That means you'll lose the information in this fields though. What about simply moving the deleted user to a different "archive" table?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your aim here, you can do this with a single line of sql statement.

```
update users set username = CONCAT(UUID(), username) where username = "username_to_be_deleted"
```

This is quite a good attempt to keep the unique constraint, unless some wicked handed user of yours picked a username that is in the format of a unique id + some string, and it will accidentaly match. Not likely, though.

Added benefit: as UUID has a fixed format, you can always extract the original username from the encoded value.

And of course, a much better aproach, if you do not add a unique constraint on a field like this, but rather enforce uniqueness programmatically.